# PHP Scripts executed manually, but cannot do it using cron (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I made a simple PHP scripts that checks number of connections using netstat, and if number of connections is more then 200 it bans it.

When I run script manually, it completed perfectly, and ip adress with high number of connection is banned immediately (added to iptables).

However, when I run script using crontab, In log file I get response that job is completed,but actually ip adress is not added in iptables until I run script again manually.

This is how I run it in cron:
57 17 * * * /home/myapp/app1/bin/php/bin/php /home/myapp/app1/webpage/scripts/ip_blocker.php > /tmp/result.log

The result.log says:

122.242.201.30 blocked with 693 connections.
Done.

This is the script content:

```
<?php

$exceptions = [
    '127.0.0.1',
];

$max_connections = 200;

$output = null;

try{
    exec("netstat -ntu | awk '{print $ 5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n", $output);

    foreach($output as $ip_address){

        [$connections, $ip] = explode(' ', trim($ip_address));

        if($connections > $max_connections && !in_array($ip, $exceptions)){
            exec("iptables -A INPUT -s ".$ip." -j DROP");
            echo $ip." blocked with ".$connections." connections.\n";
        }
    } 

    echo "Done.\n";
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}

?>
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks

I was expecting for script to actually add rule in iptables that blocks suspicious IP.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/636442/using-iptables-without-root-privileges), you need root privileges to run `iptables`

[A post here explains how to add a job to root user crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419548/how-to-set-up-a-root-cron-job-properly)